# CalendarView close when I slide down

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I'm trying to set my calendar view and I have a problem. I set android standard CalendarView and it seems to behave ok, but there is one issue. The view close when I slide down to see the next month, with actual date picked. Can someone help me with this issue? I guess it's not very hard to solve, but I can't and I'm stucked.

I made everything like here:
http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-calendarview.html (second example)
or even here:
http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-calender-view.html

It's standard implementation.

Comment: Please show your code. Is it simple activity with CalendarView added via XML?

Comment: My code looks almost exactly like in first link - second example.

Comment: I've created project using second example from first link - works as expected, Activity with Calendar View is not closed on swipe down. Please check this code: https://github.com/jskierbi/sample-date-selection. Also, if you cannot manage to fix the issue, please provide your code so I can reproduce it.

Comment: @jskierbi I'm surprised. Let me paste my code:
calendar class: http://paste.ofcode.org/hSdXjaCnVeTmkjc9VrtRQx
parent activity class: http://paste.ofcode.org/38X2UJHtj8d9wc9PCM3G3iE
I can't see the difference and the reason why my code act like this and your not :/

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you tried to build my project from github? Are you getting proper behaviour or is it also broken?

Comment: @jskierbi It act the same. Your code, I mean. I can swipe down but only for 3 lines, where line (of week) with actual date is first row of calendar widget, the view closes. Probably, because marked day is gone (in some way) and listener act like this (but it's only my guess).

Comment: Ok, on 5.0+ it was working okay, on pre 5.0 there was a problem. Check out my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the listener is called both when user selects new date or when scrolls to other month.

Here is solution:

```java
public class CalendarViewActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = CalendarViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    private long initialDate;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CalendarView calendar = new CalendarView(this);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(mDateSetListener);

        // Save initial date of calendar
        initialDate = calendar.getDate();

        setContentView(calendar);
    }

    private CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener mDateSetListener = new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            if (view.getDate() == initialDate) {
                // Listener called but user have not selected date
                return;
            }

            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;

            view.getDate();

            String selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" ").toString();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("dateSelected", selectedDate);

            //Add the set of extended data to the intent and start it
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But! There is a but. When I click on actual date on the calendar (26-04 right now) nothing happens. I understand why, but I don't know how to solve this little problem. It should select even this date.

Comment: You're not able to select initially selected date on CalendarView even without this workaround. Note that you're registering `onDateChangeListener` which is called when date changes - and selecting same date does not change selected date.